# Lazy loading a user control - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajax.net

I am using the lazy load approach for loading the user control content by using the timer method outlined here:

http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/lazy-loading-ascx-usercontrol-or-something-else-at-loadtime/

It works great when there's only one user control, but when there are multiple ones, it first renders the page, then renders the User control 1 and ***waits*** for the timer click event to be completed before it gets to the User control 2's timer click.

I want more of a async call approach where the timer events of all user controls are independently fired instead one after the other (it appears that this is possible in portals like dropthings or pageflakes that ***dont*** use client side ajax methods)

Is this possible? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

a friend did something similar for some usercontrols that took very long to render; check here: http://ivowiblo.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/asp-net-webforms-lazypanel-deferred-content-loading-in-webforms/

hope it helps

Comment: This actually requires you to set a property to define how long before a ajax call is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://encosia.com/2007/09/19/aspnet-ajax-timer-trouble-location-is-key/

and look at the "pop quiz" at the end and the comment by Maurice.

Comment: That doesn't answer the issue I am having. I have the timer outside the Updatepanel and set enabled to false after the first time it runs.

Comment: That's different than what's in the link you included...maybe posting code would be helpful.